Issue with JS Rendering in scrapy-playwright While Taking Google News Screenshots
I am having a problem with scrapy-playwright. I am trying to take a screenshot of Google News for practice crawling.
In my case, I added URL parameters cd_max and cd_min to select a specific period, but it doesn’t seem to work as expected.
I suspect that my scrapy-playwright JavaScript rendering isn’t functioning properly. Here is the code I’m working with:
import scrapy


class ScreenshotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com/search?q=google&tbm=nws&lr=lang_en&start=0&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/2023,cd_max:12/31/2023"]
    custom_settings = {
        "PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE": "firefox",
        "PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS": {
            "headless": False,
        },
        "DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS": {
            "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
        },
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                meta=dict(
                    playwright=True,
                    playwright_include_page=True,  # 페이지 객체를 포함
                    java_script_enabled=True,
                ),
                callback=self.take_screenshot,
            )

    async def take_screenshot(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.screenshot(path="screenasdasdsshot.png", full_page=True)
        await page.close()
        self.log(f"Screenshot saved for {response.url}")


I tried to take a screenshot with Selenium, and it worked perfectly!
However, I still can’t figure out why my scrapy-playwright setup isn’t working.
And here is the failure Result : result image
And this image is what i expected :
expecting image
